# Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, server-configuration

I deployed my **ruby(using rbenv) on rails app** in Ubuntu 14.04 server with nginx/passenger/WebRick/, when i ran the server in production environment, the site was rendered perfectly without any problem,but when i logged out of the ssh connection, the site was rendered blank, no errors, just a blank white page.

when i re-establish the ssh connection, that is log-in to the server, i get the page completely !

the logs, gave me this error,

> Errno::EACCES (Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -
>   /home/username/appname)

Screenshot of error log :
http://postimg.org/image/iolw2rwdr/
http://postimg.org/image/phsel5skd/

Comment: Just give the right permission with right owner in your Ubuntu server for `home/username/appname`

Answer (score 7):

`EACCESS` error means that process cannot write to that location.

You can try changing the ownershop to your current user (`whoami`) like this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.appname
```

Note: This requires that the user has permission to change the directory permission. If the user does not, you may have to sign in with a user with more privileges.